# What is the fastest way to remove a number from the beginning of so many files?

Tags: regex, bash, performance, shell, text-processing

I have 1000 files each having one million lines. Each line has the following form:

```
a number,a text
```

I want to remove all of the numbers from the beginning of every line of every file. including the ,

Example:

```
14671823,aboasdyflj -> aboasdyflj
```

What I'm doing is:

```
os.system("sed -i -- 's/^.*,//g' data/*")
```

and it works fine but it's taking a huge amount of time.

What is the fastest way to do this?

I'm coding in python.

Comment: I can't say what the *best* method is, but in terms of regex, you can reduce the number of steps taken. Use `^[^,]*,` instead. Better yet, use `^\d+,`

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call making calls to external programs "coding in Python", but ultimately, that's probably as fast as you can make it unless you can tweak the matching in `sed` to do less work... other than that - it's going to be dependent on your system load and how fast your drives are.

Comment: that's not coding in python. Coding that in python would probably be slower.

Comment: `"sed -i -- 's/^.*,//' data/*"` would be slightly faster (dropping the `g`)

Comment: is there number in the second field?

Comment: Would you be so kind to tell me how many percent it will improve it? Or tell me how I can find out how many steps are taken?

Comment: @JonClements I mentioned I'm coding in python in case someone had a better idea to use some python libraries instead of calling sed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I thought maybe there is some python wrappers for some c codes that work so fast.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay your current regex (against the input you provided) [shows 15 steps at ~196ms](https://regex101.com/r/PVwlR2/1). Changing the pattern to `^\d+,` [shows 4 steps at ~34ms](https://regex101.com/r/PVwlR2/2)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yes there can be numbers in second field too.

Comment: If you're going to call sed/awk et al., I'd at least switch your `os.system` call to a `subprocess.call` or similar though...

Comment: @JonClements I'd advise OP to remove the python tag. This hasn't anything to do with python

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But I would accept any answer that would use any python code that are faster than this.

Comment: I don't think python can beat the native tools described below ... unless you're running windows and they're not installed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is much faster:

```
cut -f2 -d ',' data.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt data.txt
```

On a file with 11 million rows it took less than one second.

To use this on several files in a directory, use:

```sh
TMP=/pathto/tmpfile
for file in dir/*; do
    cut -f2 -d ',' "$file" > $TMP && mv $TMP "$file"
done
```

A thing worth mentioning is that it often takes much longer time to do stuff in place rather than using a separate file. I tried your sed command but switched from in place to a temporary file. Total time went down from 26s to 9s.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't do `cut -f2 -d ',' "$file" > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt "$file"`

Comment: @yukashimahuksay You could do that, but what if you have a file whose actual name is `tmp.txt`? If you want it to work that way, then just change the first line to `TMP=tmp.txt` or something.

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU `awk` (to leverage the `-i inplace` editing of file) with `,` as the field separator, *no expensive Regex manipulation*:

```
awk -F, -i inplace '{print $2}' file.txt
```

For example, if the filenames have a common prefix like `file`, you can use shell globbing:

```
awk -F, -i inplace '{print $2}' file*
```

`awk` will treat each file as different argument while applying the in-place modifications.

---

As a side note, you could simply run the shell command in the shell directly instead of wrapping it in `os.system()` which is insecure and deprecated BTW in favor of `subprocess`.

Answer (score 2):

that's probably pretty fast & native python. Reduced loops and using `csv.reader` & `csv.writer` which are compiled in most implementations:

```
import csv,os,glob
for f1 in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    f2 = f1+".new"
    with open(f1) as fr, open(f2,"w",newline="") as fw:
        csv.writer(fw).writerows(x[1] for x in csv.reader(fr))
    os.remove(f1)
    os.rename(f2,f1)  # move back the newfile into the old one
```

maybe the `writerows` part could be even faster by using `map` & `operator.itemgetter` to remove the inner loop:

```
csv.writer(fw).writerows(map(operator.itemgetter(1),csv.reader(fr)))
```

Also:

- it's portable on all systems including windows without MSYS installed
- it stops with exception in case of problem avoiding to destroy the input
- the temporary file is created in the same filesystem on purpose so deleting+renaming is super fast (as opposed to moving temp file to input across filesystems which would require `shutil.move` & would copy the data)

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of your multicore system, along with the tips of other users on handling a specific file faster.

```
FILES = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
CORES = 4

q = multiprocessing.Queue(len(FILES))

for f in FILES:
    q.put(f)

def handler(q, i):
    while True:
        try:
            f = q.get(block=False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            return
        os.system("cut -f2 -d ',' {f} > tmp{i} && mv tmp{i} {f}".format(**locals()))

processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=handler, args=(q, i)) for i in range(CORES)]

[p.start() for p in processes]
[p.join() for p in processes]

print "Done!"
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to be in python3? I think most of the people who are going to read this in the future won't use python2.

Comment: Does multiprocessing really make a difference? I suspect that the IO is the most demanding part here.

Comment: `[p.start() for p in processes]` is unpythonic: don't use listcomps for side effects

Comment: @klutt: no need to bother multiprocessing. Multithreading does the same thing as system creates a new process anyway.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, but either way it seems to just add complexity and is possibly even slower.